# Log4j2 configuration broken on ubuntu 20.04 (Getting garbled logs)

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j2

log4j2 configuration was working fine on ubuntu 14 but start getting garbled logs when I deployed application on ubuntu 20.04 machines. I am using following log4j2.xml file configuration and dependencies to setup log4j2. I am not getting any compile time error or runtime error but not getting logs properly. I don't understand how ubuntu 20.04 can affect logging things of application. Getting garbled logs how can we avoid garbled logs ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="logtofile"
                     fileName="/home/ci/logs/test-file.log"
                     filePattern="/home/ci/logs/test-file.%d.log.gz">
            <ThresholdFilter level="warn"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5p %d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX} [%15.15t] %c - %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- Async Appender -->
        <Async name="async" bufferSize="512" blocking="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="logtofile"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <loggers>
        <logger name="com.test.log" level="info"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework.amqp" level="info"/>
        <!-- Root Logger -->
        <ROOT level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="async" />
        </ROOT>
    </loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.33</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "garbled logs"?

Comment: Hi @tgdavies, few logs come properly and sometimes I get like @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^

Comment: which version of JDK are you using in those 2 ubuntu ?

Comment: Check with `lsof /home/ci/logs/test-file.log` if other applications open the same file or if a single application opens it multiple times. Is the file opened in "append mode" (which should be the default)?

Comment: @SeanH, ubuntu 14.04.6 --> openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1~14.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
ubuntu 20.04.4 --> openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz, Correct but I did not change anything lsof /home/ci/logs/test-file.log

java    2511621 root  132w   REG   0,56 85503275 214855963 /home/ci/logs/cpa-datamapper.log